# Custom List of Listing Page Numbers Not Working

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, titletoc

So I have been using this particular latex template for a while now and I keep adding and changing it to be what I want. Recently I tried reformatting to get rid of the leading dots in the TOC, LOF, LOT, and LOL, and I managed to remove all of them by renewing the command `\cftdot` but this didn't seem to work for the LOL.

I used the `\titlecontents` command from the `titletoc` package to change the settings of the LOL, but this put the page numbers out of alignment with the rest of the lists. I have tried `\hfill` and `\titlerule*[0.0em]{.}` before the `\contentspage` to fix the problem, but neither has worked.

The current working example is being demonstrated with `\hfill`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\geometry{margin = 1.0in}
 \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification = centering]{caption}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Scripts}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Script}
\contentsuse{lstlisting}{lol}
\titlecontents{lstlisting}[1.5em]
        {\hspace{2.3em}}
        {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
        {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
        {\hfill\contentspage}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfoutput=1 
\hypersetup{
    unicode=false,
    pdftoolbar=true,
    pdfmenubar=true,
    pdffitwindow=true,
    pdfstartview={FitH},
    pdftitle={Title},
    pdfauthor={Author},
    pdfsubject={Subject},
    pdfcreator={Producer},
    pdfproducer={Producer},
    pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,
    pdfnewwindow=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings


\section{Here is A Section}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{boats}
\caption{A boat}
\end{figure}

\begin{table} [H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c }
Title 1 & Title 2 \\ \hline 
Stuff & More stuff 
\end{tabular}
\caption{A Table}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{lstlisting}[language = Matlab, basicstyle = \scriptsize, numberstyle = \scriptsize, caption = A Listing]
%%
clear;clc;close all;format compact;
%%
x = 5;
y = 6;
x + y = z;
disp(z);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

As can be seen in the example below, the page number for the listing is indented for some reason that I have not been able to figure out. I'm sure it's easy but I just haven't found it.
[image: Example of the LaTeX output]

As a note, I use significantly more packages and modifications than this, but these are the most basic ones for which it will still compile properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tocloft` hooks only into the standard `ToC`, `LoF` and `LoT` commands and files and those which are defined using `\newlistof`.

All of this is not covered for the `LoL`, which uses the traditional setup of `\l@...` like macros.

In `listings.sty` we find

```
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{#1}{#2}}
```

which is the relevant macro for the line setting in content lists. The next level deeper we find `\@dottedtocline` which is a LaTeX kernel macro, using `\@dotsep` as the separating space between two of the contentsline dots. The default value is `4.5`. By increasing this number to 5000 (which is really large), the dots are most probably out of sight here.

I did not want to change `\@dotsep` globally, so I patched the `\l@lstlisting` command (using a group to drop the settings after `\l@lstlisting` was used)

```
\makeatletter % Patching to prevent interference
\xpatchcmd{\l@lstlisting}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{#1}{#2}}{%
  \begingroup\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{5000}\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{#1}{#2}\endgroup}{%
}{}
\makeatother
```

Here is the code (`titletoc` related stuff commented out)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\geometry{margin = 1.0in}
 \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification = centering]{caption}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}
%\usepackage{titletoc}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{\cftnodots}

\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{List of Scripts}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Script}


\makeatletter % Patching to prevent interference
\xpatchcmd{\l@lstlisting}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{#1}{#2}}{%
  \begingroup\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{5000}\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{#1}{#2}\endgroup}{%
}{}
\makeatother
%\contentsuse{lstlisting}{lol}
%\titlecontents{lstlisting}[1.5em]
%        {\hspace{2.3em}}
%        {\contentslabel{2.3em}}
%        {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
%        {\hfill\contentspage}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfoutput=1 
\hypersetup{
    unicode=false,
    pdftoolbar=true,
    pdfmenubar=true,
    pdffitwindow=true,
    pdfstartview={FitH},
    pdftitle={Title},
    pdfauthor={Author},
    pdfsubject={Subject},
    pdfcreator={Producer},
    pdfproducer={Producer},
    pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,
    pdfnewwindow=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings


\section{Here is A Section}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 2cm]{boats}
\caption{A boat}
\end{figure}

\begin{table} [H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c }
Title 1 & Title 2 \\ \hline 
Stuff & More stuff 
\end{tabular}
\caption{A Table}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{lstlisting}[language = Matlab, basicstyle = \scriptsize, numberstyle = \scriptsize, caption = A Listing]
%%
clear;clc;close all;format compact;
%%
x = 5;
y = 6;
x + y = z;
disp(z);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much! @ChristianHupfer